# Set the font type of text in tabular environment

Tags: fonts

I am using the example given [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_typefaces) to set the font type of text in tabular environment

```
\begin{column}{\colwidth}

\begin{exampleblock}{}
\vspace{1cm}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|a|c|c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
\rowcolor{LightCyan}
{\fontfamily{bch}\selectfont
Name & H&R&M&O\\ 
\hline
Pancake&-&-&-&-\\
}
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
  \end{exampleblock}

\end{column}
```

The complete file is available [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/czzvxywvzvcv)

However, when I use `\fontfamily{bch}\selectfont` in the above code, the font type changes only for the first entry `Name`.
The font type of rest of the entries don't change.

Could someone suggest how to set a single font type, including tables and text, for my complete document?
[image]

EDIT: Complete code

```
% Gemini theme
% https://github.com/anishathalye/gemini
%
% We try to keep this Overleaf template in sync with the canonical source on
% GitHub, but it's recommended that you obtain the template directly from
% GitHub to ensure that you are using the latest version.

\documentclass[final,xcolor=x11names,compress,dvipsnames]{beamer}

% ====================
% Packages
% ====================

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%==============================
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{tgbonum}
%==============================
\usepackage[size=custom,width=118,height=146,scale=1.0]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\colorlet{ProcessBlue}{blue!50!cyan}


\newlength{\sepwidth}
\newlength{\colwidth}
\setlength{\sepwidth}{0.04\paperwidth}
\setlength{\colwidth}{0.44\paperwidth}

\newcommand{\separatorcolumn}{\begin{column}{\sepwidth}\end{column}}

\title{Title}

\author{--}

\institute{---} % Institution(s)

% ====================
% Body
% ====================

\begin{document}
%=====================
%======================
\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{block}{A block}
\end{block}
\begin{columns}[t]
\separatorcolumn

\begin{column}{\colwidth}

\begin{exampleblock}{}
\vspace{1cm}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|a|c|c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
{\fontfamily{bch}\selectfont
Name & H&R&M&O\\ 
\hline
Pancake&-&-&-&-\\
}
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
  \end{exampleblock}

\end{column}

\separatorcolumn

\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%` always try to avoid scaling tables, it forces inconsistent font sizes and rule widths and ther is almost always a better way.

Comment: each cell is a tex group, put the font change before the table if it should apply to the whole table.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! Adding font change before table works. Could you please suggest if there is a way to set same font type to the whole document? For instance, I have set the font type of the tabular environment. But, now when equations are added using `begin{equation}`, the font type appears to be different for equations.

Comment: math mode always uses a different font, very few fonts are suitable for text and math, but also it is very rare to use a low level setting like `\fontfamily{bch}\selectfont` within the document, normally you set up the fonts in the preamble and then just use `\rmfamily` or `\bfseries` etc, so that if you change teh font family for the document you just change it in one place not all through the document, but that is a separate question can not really be answered here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each cell is a tex group, put the font change before the table if it should apply to the whole table.